# Making a graph in web2py from date

Tags: web2py

In my web2py application, in my `db` I have a field named `Date_Of_Sale` which has type `date`. I have to make a bar graph according to the month of sale of my product.

How can I extract the month from the date the user inputs for each individual sale?

My `db` is as follows-

```
db.define_table('Sales',
Field('customer_name','string'),
Field('mobile_number','string'),
Field('Date_Of_Sale','date')
)
```